# Use TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR when screen off

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sensors

I'm developing an application which uses the TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR. I want to detect whether user is walking even when the screen of the phone is off. But the sensor TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR does not work when the screen is off.
So I use PowerManager/WakeLock to make the CPU not hibernate. But it STILL not work.
As a comparison, I add a magnetic sensor listener and the step detector listener to my demo app, when screen on, both of them can recieve data, but when the screen is off, only the magnetic sensor can recieve data.

```
        PowerManager manager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Then:

```
        stepDetectorSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);

        sensorManager.registerListener(stepDetectorListener, stepDetectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Then:

```
        magnetSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorManager.registerListener(magnetSensorListener, magnetSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

And:

```
        stepDetectorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
                //NO DATA when screen off
            }

        };


        magnetSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
                 //DATA when screen off
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if user is walking - you got to take completely different approach. Google released an [`ActivityRecognitionApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html). This framework allows you to track user's current activity (such as [WALKING](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#WALKING), [RUNNING](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#RUNNING) and others).

It also allows you to track activity when app is in background.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it. And could you tell me why the step sensor does not work when screen is off? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know - never tried using STEP_DETECTOR in the background